# Why is $x^{1/3}$ not differentiable?

Tags: derivatives, differential-topology

The problem says

> On $\mathbb{R}^1$consider $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^{1/3}$ both $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Consider atlases $\alpha_1=\{(\mathbb{R},f)\}$ and $\alpha_2=\{(\mathbb{R},g)\}$. Show that both atlases define a $C^{\infty}$ structure on $\mathbb{R}$ (I've done this) and explain why $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ aren't compatible.

Now, I see no reason why they aren't compatible, looking at the definition. I need that the transiition functions $f (g^{-1})$ and $g(f^{-1})$ both to be $C^{\infty}$ in this case.

However, the solution says

> Consider the transition function $f(g^{-1})$. This satisfies $f(g^{-1
> })(x)=x^{1/3}$ which is not differentiable hence not smooth.

Uhm, it is...? I mean, here $(x^{1/3})'=\frac{1}{3}x^{-2/3}$ there's a derivative. yep it's differentiable. And I can keep on going. 
Is "differentiable" defined in different ways in mathematics depending on the area??? This is "differentiable manifolds" and I don't recall it being different.

why is $x^{1/3}$ not differentiable?

Comment: What's the value of $f'(x)$ at $x=0$?

Comment: erm,,,$0^{1/3}=0$. Cube root of $0$ is, $0$ no?

Comment: What is the _derivative_ at $x=0$?

Comment: That needs to take the limit but, wait, why are we talking about values at a specific point? Does being differentiable come with the package that every point in the derivative is well-defined??

Comment: continuous at $x=0$ not diffrentiable at $x=0$

Comment: Yes, differentiability is a global property. If the derivative does not exist even at a single point in the domain, it's not differentiable.

Comment: I thought I learned differentiation at high school and I feel like I should go back. I don't understand at all. So all along, functions like $x^{-1}$ were never differentiable while the derivative CAN be found?? Confused majorly. So it makes no sense to ask questions like "find the derivative of $x^{-1}$ or $x^{1/2}$" etc then. It's not differentiable so it doesn;t exist then.

Comment: Well sure, the derivative can be found *at some points*, but not others (like the origin in this case). You can say "this function is differentiable at a point $x$", or "this function is differentiable on this interval/in this region". But if you just say "this function is differentiable", it has to be so everywhere.

Comment: @JohnTrail $x^{-1}$ is differentiable at all points except $0$.

Comment: Isn't that the concept of continuity?? When the function cannot be defined at some points? I thought differentiable and continuously differentiable are two different things...

Comment: Smooth functions have bounded derivatives. Yours does not.

Comment: No, that's not the concept of continuity. This is indeed two different things. Of course, discontinuous functions cannot be differentiable. But not all continuous functions are differentiable, either.

Comment: The function $1/x$ is differentiable where it is defined. $|x|$ and $\sqrt[3]x$ are differentiable at almost all points, but they are not  _differentiable functions_.

Comment: Furthermore, what about $x<0$? The text you have quoted says nothing else about $g$ except that it is real-valued. This necessarily implies that $\mathop{\textrm{dom}} g$---the set of points over which $g$ is defined---is $[0,+\infty)$, because $x^{1/3}$ is not defined for negative $x$ in a strictly real context. A more esoteric property of a differentiable function is that it must have an open domain. For instance, $h(x)=1/x$, explicitly defined to have $\mathop{\textrm{dom}} h=(0,+\infty)$, *is* differentiable.

Comment: okay, so i'm just going to get things straight and memorize since an exam's up tomorow ; diferentiable means that the function has points defined *everywhere * in the domain. Otherwise, not differentiable.

Comment: That's a good plan. :-)

Comment: @amcalde: Regarding your comment "*It is not differentiable because the formula for the derivative has no meaning when you plug in zero*, this is a little misleading because the formula was (presumably) obtained under the assumption that $x \neq 0.$ To show non-differentiability at $x=0$ requires something else, such as examining the limit of difference quotients based at $x=0.$

Comment: @JohnTrail The formulation in your last comment is horribly ambiguous. Actually, the property that is written in your comment characterizes a function defined everywhere on its domain, a property which does not involve differentiability (and which is automatically true, but this is another subject).